# Capture TAB keydown and trigger other keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the behaviour of selects in an html form.

I would like that when a user navigates the form using the keyboard, if they are selecting an element and presses tab, the element is selected and the focus switches to the next form input. Normally, you need to press enter to select the element and then you can use tab to switch to the next one. If enter isn't pressed, no option is selected.

To do this, I want to capture the TAB keypress and trigger an ENTER keypress followed by a TAB.

This is what I have for now:

```
     $('form[class="ui form"]').on('keydown', 'div[class="ui fluid selection dropdown active visible"]', function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if (keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var y = jQuery.Event('keydown', {which: 13});
            $(this).trigger(y);
            var x = jQuery.Event('keydown', {which: 9});
            $(this).trigger(x);
        }
    });
```

Here is a demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sL7tnfm6/)

The code 'works' up to e.preventDefault(), the tab keypress doesn't switch the focus to the next input. However, the enter and tab actions aren't triggered, so nothing happens. What should I do ?
Thank you in advance !

UPDATE 10/10: Found the problem! Triggering event x (tab keypress) makes the code enter an infinite loop. Therefore the whole approach is wrong. I'll soon post an answer.

Comment: What happens if you replace `which` with `keyCode`?

Comment: @BenM nothing changes

Comment: Did you try firing keypress instead?

Comment: @JuanMendes I have tried that as well, the JSFiddle demo shows the problem I encounter

Comment: When I try it passing `which`, it does work https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/sL7tnfm6/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The draft code in the question triggers an infinite loop. The key point in the problem is capturing the selected (active) element when the user presses TAB and switches the focus to the next element.

So, it is better to use a function called `onblur`:

```
$('form[class="ui form"]').on('blur', '.dropdown', function () {
        var y = jQuery.Event('keydown', {which: 13});
        $(this).trigger(y);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try it passing `which`as the event object, it does work jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/sL7tnfm6/5

```
    $('form[class="ui form"]').on('keydown', 'div[class="ui fluid selection dropdown active visible"]', function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if (keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var y = jQuery.Event('keydown', {which: 13});
            $(this).trigger(y);

        }
    });
```

Comment: This part does work, but it doesn't solve the problem: focus stays on the current dropdown instead of focusing the next form element